# Formatting code in VS 2013 doesn't work at all

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My my Visual Studio 2013 I cannot format the code. Neither via the menu (Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document), no via the hotkey (Ctrl+E,D -- I've assigned it myself). Nothing at all. What's up with it?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the code first?

Comment: @MartinEvans, no, because I'm choosing to format the whole document.

Comment: Not entirely sure why the down-vote. That action implies that VS is reliable on all installations which I suspect is not true

Comment: I think you need to reset settings and see if it works but you either need to backup your preferences

Comment: Does the code compile?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

1. Ctrl + K + D to format all
2. Ctrl + K + F to format selected code